# Adding/deleting languages from control panel

Tags: configuration, sitecore-client, multilingual

[image]

Is it adding/deleting a language from control panel is same as adding/deleting in content editor `/sitecore/system/Languages`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL/DR;

There is no difference

#### Long version:

This is the code that gets executed when you use the `Delete Language` option from the control panel:

```
  protected void Delete()
  {
    Job job = Context.Job;
    Assert.IsNotNull((object) job, "Job is null");
    Database database = Factory.GetDatabase(this._databaseName);
    Assert.IsNotNull((object) database, "Database");
    try
    {
      foreach (Language language in this._languages)
      {
        ID languageItemId = LanguageManager.GetLanguageItemId(language, database);
        Item obj = database.GetItem(languageItemId);
        Assert.IsNotNull((object) obj, "Item is null: /sitecore/system/languages/{0}", (object) language.Name);
        if (Settings.RecycleBinActive)
        {
          Log.Audit((object) this, "Recycle Language: {0}", new string[1]{ language.Name });
          obj.Recycle();
        }
        else
        {
          Log.Audit((object) this, "Delete Language: {0}", new string[1]{ language.Name });
          obj.Delete();
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      job.Status.Failed = true;
      job.Status.Messages.Add(ex.ToString());
    }
    job.Status.State = JobState.Finished;
  }
}
```

As you can see, ultimately it does the same thing as removing the language item would. There is some extra logging around it, and it has a nice form for you to select the language to delete first.

The code is not run within any disablers so all the same `item:deleted` events and `item:deleting` events would run in the same way.